# Getting the wrong hashes for bitcoin core packages

Tags: signature

I've been playing around learning more about Bitcoin and was following [this](https://21.co/learn/digital-signatures/#using-hashes-and-cryptographic-signatures-to-verify-data-integrity) tutorial from 21.co on digital signatures.

When I open the SHA256SUMS.asc file and try to verify the packages, I get different hashes than what's in the file.

```
curl -O https://bitcoin.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.11.0.tar.gz

shasum -a 256 bitcoin-core-0.11.0.tar.gz
```

This gives the following output:

```
69b00985c84e6633cc2e518914436ce55666cc10d1edf15ee442758d9f8d5219  bitcoin-core-0.11.0.tar.gz
```

Which is very different from what is in the file:

```
c7a5e496d7c31bdc10d2c0c79dfcf9aca69f9520579917c7d3e95868b2127707  bitcoin-0.11.0-osx64.tar.gz
```

NOTE: I'm using a different command then what is mentioned in the tutorial for checking the hashes. `shasum -a 256` instead of `sha256sum`.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

You are hashing the 404 page returned by bitcoin.org. You can see this by running:

```
$ curl -s https://bitcoin.org/bin/file-does-not-exist | sha256sum
69b00985c84e6633cc2e518914436ce55666cc10d1edf15ee442758d9f8d5219  -
$ curl -s https://bitcoin.org/bin/file-does-not-exist2 | sha256sum
69b00985c84e6633cc2e518914436ce55666cc10d1edf15ee442758d9f8d5219  -
```

You should instead run

```
$ curl -O https://bitcoin.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.10.0/bitcoin-0.10.0.tar.gz
$ sha256sum bitcoin-0.10.0.tar.gz # shasum -a 256 would also work
```

This gives me

```
a516cf6d9f58a117607148405334b35d3178df1ba1c59229609d2bcd08d30624  bitcoin-0.10.0.tar.gz
```

which is the SHA256SUM listed in the associated `SHA256SUMS.asc` file.